# Django button ajax click

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django

I have some HTML that Django is rendering well. I'd like to click a button on the HTML and have that cause an event to fire in the view.

It doesn't look like the button is causing the `post` to fire. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my `views.py` code:

```
def log(request):
  if not request.POST:
    template = loader.get_template('log.html')
    html = template.render(Context())
    return HttpResponse(html)
  print "Post"
```

This is my `log.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#update_log_button").bind("button", function(){
        $.post("hello");
        return false;
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <span>SPHIINX Log</span>
</p>
<p>
    <textarea cols="2" name="log" rows="25"></textarea>
     <input id="update_log_button" name="update_log" type="button" value="Update Log"/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason Why you are not using the `click` event directly?

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#update_log_button").click(function(){
        $.post(
         url : "/hello/",
         dataType:"html",
         success: function(data, status, xhr){
            //do something with your data
        }
        );
        return false;
    });
 });
</script>
```

If the button is dynamically created then you may want to use the `bind` function to attach `click` event handler to the element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
    $("#update_log_button").bind('click', function(){
        $.post(
         url : "/hello/",
         dataType:"html",
         success: function(data, status, xhr){
            //do something with your data
        }
        );

        return false;
    });
   });
</script>
```

Try this URL to include the JQuery library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Probably not I have changed the answer...Mind the url. Change to what you are using!

Comment: That didn't work for me either.  I'm sure, it is my lack of understanding of JS / AJAX.

Comment: What is the easiest way to get my views.py to respond to a button click from the .html?

Comment: Sure, I get:

No Javascript on this page

If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).

Comment: I guess you script tags are fine but where is you jquery lib?

Comment: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]  

url : "/log/",

/log/ (line 21, col 24)

Comment: Again, I'm very new to JS, how do I include jquery into my django .html file?

Is there some kind of #include analog?

Comment: Updated the answer include this in your html file to load jquery lib

Comment: Thank you

I was missing that