# Django: How to call a function once a button is clicked?

Tags: python, html, django, methods, view

I have a method written in my views.py that sends a sub-process command.

I want to be able to click a button on my Django application and it initiates the method I wrote.

How can I do this?

This is currently my function in my views.py

```
    def send_command(request):
        output = subprocess.check_output('ls', shell=True)
        print(output)
        return render(request, 'button.html')
```

I also have a button in a .html file

```
    <center><button type='submit' class='btn btn-lg'>Button</button></center>
```

I'm VERY new to this so but any help would be appreciated. Please feel free to ask for more info.

Comment: @Taylor I believe the question you linked relates to Tkinter and not Django/html

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733767/django-button-ajax-click) may help

Comment: @an0o0nym Great, I'll check it out! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sending content which will be saved in the server you could change your button to behave like a url

url.py

```
from views import send_command

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^send_command$', send_command, name='send_command'),
]
```

html

```
<a href="{% url 'send_command' %}" class='btn btn-lg'>Button</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. However, Is there any way to call the method without switching pages?

Comment: Yes, use ajax like the comment of @an0o0nym

Comment: great, I'll try both! I appreciate it!